# LinkedList adding elements with a change or remove callback

Tags: java, linked-list

When we add elements to the LinkedList we only have boolean which is always true.

Is there an implementation of LinkedList that, in response to adding, gives some interface, thanks to which we can change the value, or delete it of the added node at any time?

I need something like the following

```java
LinkedList<A> list = new LinkedList<>();
LinkedListNode<A> node = list.add(object);
// After some amount of time, with multiple modifications of LinkedList
node.remove();

public interface LinkedListNode<T> {
    void set(T t);

    void remove();
}
```

In default java LinkedList implementation, only way to delete element is `list.remove(object)`, but it will iterate over all elements of the collection.

PS: I don't want to use a HashSet for this

Comment: What scenario are you thinking of using your LinkedList in?

Comment: @mrkachariker To add an event listener. So that when subscribing to an event, I get the opportunity to unsubscribe from it

Comment: Why not use an ArrayList for that?

Comment: I think LinkedList perfect for this usage. Because in array list you need iterate list to find and remove element, in node you can just remove node, with O(1)

Comment: It's actually the other way around (as long as you have the index of the element you want to remove).

Comment: Also, why would you not want to use HashSet for this?

Comment: Indeed. A Set (e.g. LinkedHashSet, which retains original insertion order) could solve this, even if your objects look identical (e.g. the number "1" multiple times), as long as you wrap them in respectively NEW instances of a custom wrapper class. ... The only problem is if you want to insert new entries instead of adding them to the end.

Comment: Just the index of the inserted element will not work, because if elements are deleted after them, then its index will also change accordingly

Comment: I just think it makes the most sense to use LinkedList in this situation since we are literally taking advantage of its data structure. I mean doubly linked list, like default java LinkedList